# Change the value of a selected radio button on pageload

Tags: asp-classic, radio-button

I have the following code that renders two radio buttons for the selections of Yes and No. On pageload, No is always selected, but I need Yes to be the default (I'm not the best at this type of coding, I've tried some things and my research hasn't clued me in). How can I adjust it? Thanks in advance.

```
<tr>
    <td> Residential?&nbsp;

        <input type="radio" name="Residential" value="0" onclick="document.QuoteInfo.save.value='0';document.OrderPanel.submit();" <%If Not Session("oDE").Fieldvalue("QUOTES","Residential") Then Response.Write " checked "%>  />
            No&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" onclick="document.QuoteInfo.save.value='0';document.OrderPanel.submit();" name="Residential" value="1" <%If Session("oDE").Fieldvalue("QUOTES","Residential") Then Response.Write " checked "%>  />
            Yes

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm afraid, to answer this we need to know what kind of object stored in `Session("oDE")`.

Comment: to be honest, I'm not sure, my knowledge of this type of coding isn't too vast. would the complete file be of more help? I didn't paste the whole thing because it's roughly 2300 lines.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Okay. If I understand correctly you don't need asp blocks to handling default `checked` attribute. Try to add manually.</strike>

```html
<input type="radio" name="Residential" value="0" onclick="document.QuoteInfo.save.value='0';document.OrderPanel.submit();" /> No&nbsp;
<input type="radio" onclick="document.QuoteInfo.save.value='0';document.OrderPanel.submit();" name="Residential" value="1" checked="checked" /> Yes
```

**Edit:**
I edited because you need to asp blocks. `onclick="document.QuoteInfo.save.value='0';document.OrderPanel.submit();"` this is for both of `no` and `yes`. At least, for checkbox `yes`'s onclick attribute could be `onclick="document.QuoteInfo.save.value='1';document.OrderPanel.submit();"` ?

Comment: That is forcing the No radio to always be checked, even if the user selects yes, the page refreshes and No is still selected.

Comment: Heh, now the opposite behavior, always Yes is selected.